# Limit number of posts for each category and child of, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories

I have a problem that I can not solve. As the title says, I want to define a different number of posts in each category. I tried to query posts and not work, and they leave the posts of all categories, I tried also with pre_get_posts and this works. But it only works for the parent category, and can not find a function for it to work well for the sub categories as well.

This is what I want:

```
Category Parent 1 > Posts per page 5
 subcategory > post per page 5

Category Parent 2 > Posts per page 10
 subcategory > post per page 10

Category Parent 3 > Posts per page 20
 subcategory > post per page 20
```

I tried with pre_get_posts but is_category only serves to the parent category and subcategories not.

```
 function wpse47875_change_posts_per_page( $query ) {

    if ( is_category( 'portadas-facebook' ) ){
        //Display 4 posts for category 1
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
    }


}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse47875_change_posts_per_page', 1);
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the [cat_is_ancestor_of()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of) function should do what you want.

```
$portadasCat = get_category_by_slug( 'portadas-facebook' );

$currentCatId = get_query_var( 'cat' );

if ( is_category( $portadasCat ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( $portadasCat, $currentCatId ) ){
        //Display 4 posts for category 1
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you for you help but not work with subcategory :s, any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot `cat_is_ancestor_of()` doesn't take category slug as an argument. We have to fetch the category by using `get_category_by_slug()` first. Please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, unfortunately does not work with the subcategories, any other ideas of how you could do? I thought about not using pre_get_posts, if not a template of category, but in doing so the pagination does not work